# I have a file full of SQL commands. How to insert it in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea

My file looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE book (
isbn VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(170) NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
price SMALLINT NOT NULL,
mrp SMALLINT,
pages VARCHAR(11),
lang VARCHAR(10),
dimensions VARCHAR(25),
publisher VARCHAR(200),
summary VARCHAR(MAX),
about_author VARCHAR(MAX),
review VARCHAR(MAX),
rank_ int IDENTITY(1,1),
CONSTRAINT PK_isbn PRIMARY KEY(isbn)
);

INSERT INTO book VALUES ('8129135728', 'Half Girlfriend', 'Chetan Bhagat', 80.0, 176.0, '260 pages', 'English', '13.3 x 1.8 x 19.5 cm', 'Rupa & Co; 3rd edition (1 October 2014)', '<div> Once upon a time...</div>', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO book VALUES ('8129135523', '2 States : The Story of My Marriage', 'Chetan Bhagat', 111.0, 176.0, '269 pages', 'English', '12.9 x 19.8 cm', 'Rupa Publications India (1 January 2014)', '<div> Many writers are successful...</div>', 'about author', NULL)
.
.
```

There are more rows to insert.

I ran this file's content as a query in visual studio and it worked. How can I do something like that in IntelliJ with MySQL?

I just want the content in the database. It doesn't have to be done only through IntelliJ.

Comment: Why not run that code in MySQL workbench?

Comment: save it as a text file and run it from the command line.

Comment: If you have mysql installed, you can execute something like this from command line, just make sure the database is there, or you should add CREATE DATABASE statement to the script.
mysql db_name < text_file. More details here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Just to elaborate on @McAdam331 for the newcomers; in Workbench - and it varies by Workbench release level - you will cut/paste your commands into a Script window and execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy task, use MySQL Workbench here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/